# google-apps-script alert on mobile app

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Just implemented an alert on my Google Spreadsheet App, it works via browser, but it's not working on the Google mobile app.

Below the code I am using:

```
function showAlert(currentValue) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var result = ui.alert(
     'WARNING',
     'You are modifying the cell with value ' + currentValue + ', do you want to continue?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    return true;
  } else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    return false;
  }
}
```

There's any solution to make it work on mobile app too or any other similar solution to warn the user when trying to modify a not empty cell?

Thanks.

Comment: Just use Protect ranges with or without  data validation and show warning.

Comment: How? I can only protect ranges without rules, I need the protection only if the cell is not empty

Comment: Use data validation then

Comment: I can't because I have to check the value before the edit, not the new value

Comment: Care to give a example?

Comment: When a user tries to modify an empty cell I don't need any alert, but when a user tries to modify a cell that it wasn't empty I have to show the warning.

Comment: Just use a secret validation protocol(like >999999999999999 ) with no help text w/Reject input. The previous data will be invalidating the rules, but since it's already there, it won't be a problem.

Comment: Nevertheless, it doesn't change the fact that it works in browser, but not in the mobile app - I unfortunally just encountered the same problem